# Message post on friends wall using facebook sdk from android 3.0

Tags: android

I am doing like this to post on friends wall and giving hardcoded one friends id to post if i pass me/feed instead of friend's id/feed it posts on my wall but when I put friends user id it throws exception of null onCompleted method that is overrided by me

Here is my code snippet:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", "Hi zeeshan");
        params.putString("caption", "Hello");
        Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "100004852531430/feed", params, 
                HttpMethod.POST, callback);
        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
```

Comment: Did you get writing on friends' wall permission while authenticating app?

Comment: i took publish_action and publish_stream permission

Comment: I solved it by going to my Facebook app setting>> Advanced and Disabled February 2012 changes

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: I facing same problem some. I was not able to find setting>> Advanced and Disabled February 2012 changes...have they changed the position of this setting.

Comment: Actually they have removed that thing, now if we want to post on friends wall we need to use Feed Dialog